# window.open() in button inside a web view app not working only on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I have created a web view app in swift. There I came up with one issue that following click event is not working.

```
<button onclick=" window.open('https://www.google.com/','_blank')"> click + </button>
```

It seems to be only `window.open()` having that issue in ios devices for the ios app. Any way to fix this?

Comment: A web view (`WKWebView` or `UIWebView`) doesn't have a concept of multiple windows like `Safari` does. What is the effect you're hoping the action will have?

Comment: Have you enabled javascript for the web view?

Comment: Please make sure your code doesn’t use smart quotes (`“”` and `‘’`). See [What is the difference between “ " quotes in javascript?](/q/45766066/4642212) and [Simple HTML page not loading Javascript Hello World](/q/22713330/4642212). Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: already enabled js @RickyMo

Comment: already using correct quotes. Sorry, I'll update the code in the question. @SebastianSimon